# PrimeFaces : Block Ui not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Hi i am working with **js2+ primefaces**  here is my code to block UI

```
<table>

<h:form id="main">


<tr>

<p:growl --->
    ---
    <p:dashboard   id="board" model="#{adminD.userProfl}" disabled="true">


<p:panel id="adminActivity" header="Admin Activities">
  <table id="hor-minimalist-b" >
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h:commandLink action="#{photoValidation.ooDirectory()}" name="submit" type="submit" id="convertPhotos">
            <h:outputText value="Convert All Photos in Databse "/>
            <f:ajax execute=":main:adminActivity"  render=":main:growl"/>
          </h:commandLink>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</p:panel>
</p:dashboard>

<p:blockUI block=":main:board" trigger=":main:convertPhotos">
  LOADING<br />  
  <p:graphicImage value="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>  
</p:blockUI>
```

---

here **board** is dashboard id **main** is form id

also implemented managed bean with thread.sleep of 5 seconds

Comment: for start, you better format your code properly... its not really readable that way...

Comment: can you update your example with form and dashboard?

Comment: why do you have `disabled="true"` ?

Comment: disabled reordering of panels

Comment: looks like ok. What if you remove <f:ajax execute=":main:adminActivity"  render=":main:growl"/> ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the `:main:` prefixes , since all this resides inside the same `h:form` , there no need to add that `main` prefix

Use

```
<p:blockUI block="board" trigger="convertPhotos">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing h:commandLink to p:commandLink:

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{photoValidation.ooDirectory()}"  update=":main:growl"   id="convertPhotos"><h:outputText value="Convert All Photos in Databse "/></p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code?

```
<p:blockUI block="board" trigger="adminActivity:convertPhotos">
```

It is only tipp but you can find component element by firebug or another web tool in browser.